# How to check time taken to convert java object to json in rest services

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jersey, ejb

We are using jersey rest service and exposed a service, the service taking long time for a record of ( around 5 MB ) to get from service . To figure out where is the performance bottleneck I want to know how much time it is taking when converting java object to JSON object. Is there any tool ?

```
UI ---------- REST ----------- EJB ------------- DB

UI---------35 SEC--------------EJB|---- 6Sec-----DB
```

Comment: Would there be anything wrong with using `System.currentTimeMillis()` before and after the conversion of the JSON object?

Comment: I am not sure because the method still return Java Object not The JSON, the conversion is taken care by Jersey rest framework as per my understanding

Answer (score 1):

Add the filter for your REST call, link  -https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html